Embeded excel file in word document doesnt keep file name
I am using Aspose Words Version=16.7.0.0 and i am embedding excel file in word document using the code below but i cannot preserve the file name of excel file when i open it.
The steps are:

Creating excel document and saving to memory stream:

  Workbook workbook = new Workbook(FileFormatType.Xlsx);
  workbook.FileName = filename; // (this file name is relevant)
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  workbook.Save(ms, SaveFormat.Xlsx);
  return ms;


This memory stream is read and written to temporary file using file stream.
Code:

using (MemoryStream excelFileMemoryStream = this.myService.Value.GetExcelFileContent(excelFileName))
{
     string temporaryExcelFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), excelFileName);
     using (FileStream tempFileStream = new FileStream(temporaryExcelFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
     {
         excelFileMemoryStream.WriteTo(tempFileStream);
     }
     return temporaryExcelFilePath;
}


Then i am embedding it to word document with InsertOleObject:

using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(temporaryExcelFilePath))
{
    builder.InsertOleObject(fileStream, "Excel.Sheet.12", true, iconImage);
}

The problem here is that when i open this excel file from word document, the name of excel file is not preserved.

Try inserting OLE object directly from file:
builder.InsertOleObject(@"C:\Temp\in.xlsx", false, true, null);

